# Are even greater in number, or are even greater in numbers

Tags: grammar, word-usage, singular-vs-plural

Which use of **number** / **numbers** is correct, and why?

> Future estimates of the program’s second pilot phase are even greater in **number** and reduced impact on Alaska’s pristine environment.
>
> Future estimates of the program’s second pilot phase are even greater in **numbers** and reduced impact on Alaska’s pristine environment.

Comment: It's hard to answer the question, because of ambiguity about what "numbers" refers to. As stated, it seems to refer to the number of estimates, but I imagine that it intends to refer to numbers of something being estimated. Could you clarify it, please?

Comment: It refers to: "over 21,000 pounds of plastics, 32,000 pounds of lead, 24 pounds of barium, and many other materials have been removed from the environment and disposed of properly."

Comment: So, the numbers are estimations about reductions in environmental pollutants. I mean no offense, but I think you should forget about the choice of "number/s" and recast the sentence.

Comment: Maybe along these lines:  "Estimates of the pilot program's second phase show that future reductions in pollutants are even greater, and signal reduced impact on Alaska's pristine environment."

Comment: Thanks. I revised it to: "Estimates of the program’s second phase promise to remove even more hazardous waste from Alaska’s pristine environment."

Comment: That's great, very clean.